# Problem with \textbf{} command

Tags: fonts, bold

I am using the font `Open Sans Condensed Light` for my CV. In some parts of my CV I need to bold some text, so I use `\textbf{}` command. However, it does not work.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{tccv}

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Open Sans Condensed Light} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}


\begin{document}

\section{Εκπαίδευση}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[Environmental Economics \& Management]{2012 -- 2015}
     {\textbf{MSc in Business \& Economics}}
     {University}


\end{yearlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What error message do you get printed on the terminal?

Comment: I don't get an error. The problem is that the text remains "unbold". I don't know if the problem is the font I use...

Comment: I am not sure if that light font has bold version.

Comment: having specified a light font to be the normal weight it isn't going to get the variants automatically, you'll need to declare that (presumably) you want the normal weight font to be `\bfseries`

Comment: @Sigur The .zip file with the font included `Open Sans Condensed Light `, `Open Sans Condensed Light  italic`, `Open Sans Condensed bold`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, how I will do it in the above example?

Comment: I'd need to check the fontspec manual:-), no time now will check this evening if no one has answered....

Comment: Open Sans Condensed Light has no bold version… since it is Light.It only has an italic version.  You can use Open Sans Bold (but Open Sans is not the same family as Open Sans Condensed Light).

Comment: Where did you get the font from? Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 4):

[Open Sans Condensed](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed) comes in Light, Light Italic, and Bold, with no Bold Italic.

You can use it like this:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{Open Sans Condensed Light}[
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ItalicFont={* Italic},
  BoldFont={Open Sans Condensed Bold}]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Open Sans Condensed}

  \textbf{Boldly} \textit{emphasizing} nonsense.

  \textbf{123} \textit{456} 7890
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]

If you have an old version of `fontspec`, you should put the options between `\setsansfont` and `{Open Sans Condensed Light}`; you can do that anyway if you prefer.

For reasons unknown, TeX Live includes the Condensed Light fonts but not the Condensed Bold.  You may wish to write to the package maintainer about this, but that would benefit people using `pdftex` more than `xetex` or `luatex`.

At any rate, I wouldn’t use the bold and the light together under ordinary circumstances: usually one pairs bold with regular, and semi-bold with light.